# Why doesn't readline() return original text?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, readline

I'm trying to read files and collect the data inside the files. I am looking inside my directory, moving towards the folder, and looking there.

I would like to read every line in the file.

I have read that my output looks like binary. I've tried looking around on stackoverflow. I have also made sure the file I am reading is a txt file.

```
import os

def ratio(filename):

    cwd = str(os.getcwd())    
    cwd = cwd[:-8]
    cwd = cwd + "Equities\\" + str(filename) + ".txt"
    file = open(cwd, "r")
    line_1=str(file.readline(4))
    print(line_1)
```

The `readline(4)` should return:

> Current assets

My `readline(4)` function returns:

> ÿþA\000

Comment: ```readline(4)``` doesn't read the 4th line. In python 2 it specifies the maximum number of bytes that can be read from the line. It's reading an incomplete character from the first line when you call it like that.

Comment: Is there a better function to use? Thank you!

Comment: Kinda hard to understand what you wanted to do from your question.
If you really are trying to read the fourthline (without moving offsets), you could use readlines(), which returns a list of your lines, and then read the result at cell [3]

Comment: I'd use `next(itertools.islice(file, 3, None))`; `islice` will skip lines 0, 1, 2, so `next` returns line 3 (the fourth line).

Comment: What is the `-8` supposed to skip? You probably want to use functions in `os.path` to manipulate your file paths, rather than treat them as strings.

Comment: I have a directory /Theo/, inside are two folders: equities and programs. The -8 moves back from programs so I can go forward to equities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to read a specific line try:

```
lines=file.readlines()
text = lines[4]
```

readline reads one line at a time. You can use readlines instead to read all the lines at once into a list.

As I mentioned in my comment `readline(4)` only reads 4 bytes from the first line, not the fourth line.

Comment: The function now returns '\x00\n'

Comment: Have you tried ```file=open('cwd','r',encoding='utf-8')```?

Comment: uiltins.UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: Your file probably is not encoded in utf-8. Take a look at https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html and see what it might be in. It might be one of the windows formats. You could try that to see if it will work.